# Dynamic Youtube Embed from Firebase Realtime Database in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, iframe, firebase-realtime-database, youtube

Hello Stack Overflow Community!

I really need some help with my most recent project. I am attempting to embed a Youtube Video from a Firebase Realtime Database. Inside the Database is the Embed Url, but when I try and put the data inside the src, it makes a blank iframe.

```
<iframe src="{item.embed}" />
```

[image]

What would I do to this link embeddable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use react-youtube module for this purpose which uses youtube iFrame API for videos.
Find all the documentation in below link.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube